# activeTab permissions not working as expected - Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

As per [permissions documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permission_warnings), if we have `activeTab` perimissions, we need not specify the URL based permissions

> Any of the following URLs match all hosts:
>
> ```
> http://*/*
> https://*/*
> *://*/*
> <all_urls>
> ```
>
> **Note that you may be able to avoid declaring all host permissions**
>   **using the activeTab permission.**

But this is working only once, second time getting error (extension UI is open while we try second time), if we launch the popup again by clicking extension icon it works fine.

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: 
Cannot access contents of the page. 
Extension manifest must request permission to access the respective host.
```

Following are details

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Getting started example",
  "description": "This is hello world example",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ]
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Hello World!</div>
    <input type="button" id="refreshPage" value="Refresh Page"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    function refreshPage() {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
            code: 'window.location.reload(true)'
        }, function(){
            console.log("Page refershed");
        });
    }

    document.getElementById("refreshPage").addEventListener("click", refreshPage);

});
```

If we add `"*://localhost/*"` (this works for localhost), there is another way to specify for all hosts `*://*/*` (not sure if this is right and secure way), refresh button is working multiple times without relaunching popup UI. Is there a difference between activeTab vs URL based permissions and any specific way is recommended over another due to specific reasons?

Comment: Raised a bug on Chromium. [Refer bug # 806633](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=806633) for more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **activeTab** gives permission temporarily until the tab is navigated or closed. My guess is that by reloading the tab when hitting refresh revokes the **activeTab** permissions. Avoid using `window.location.reload` or specify the url match for the domain you are trying to execute a script on.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab

> The activeTab permission gives an extension temporary access to the
>   currently active tab when the user invokes the extension - for example
>   by clicking its browser action. Access to the tab lasts until the tab
>   is navigated or closed.

Comment: Correct. There's no bug.

Comment: Given that the Chrome Web Store now mandates using activeTab, having no permission that works across a reload *is* a bug.

Comment: Agreed @user239558 why do you lose access to the content of the `activeTab` when the URL changes or it is refreshed? You have permission for that active tab, why lose that when it is still active? Also, even after you change to another tab and then back to the tab in question (making it the active tab again), you still don't regain access until you open your popup! This seems counterintuitive. Particularly when your extension is what changed `window.location.href` or reloaded the page to begin with.